# How do I add a button float above CarouselPage in Xamarin?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to add a button to this page so it stays and float above the same on the screen and doesn't scroll with the CarouselPage when I press the slide.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zdZHZ.png)

Answer (score 1):

You could use `CarouselView` instead of `CarouselPage`. You could try the code below. It use the `ContentPage` with `CarouselView` .

**Xaml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage
x:Class="CarouselPageNavigation.Page2"
xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <CarouselView Grid.Row="0" ItemsSource="{Binding colorsDataModels}">
        <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackLayout>
                    <Label
                        FontSize="Medium"
                        HorizontalOptions="Center"
                        Text="{Binding Name}" />
                    <BoxView
                        HeightRequest="200"
                        HorizontalOptions="Center"
                        VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                        WidthRequest="200"
                        Color="{Binding Color}" />
                </StackLayout>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
    </CarouselView>
    <Button
        Grid.Row="0"
        Margin="0,0,20,22"
        BackgroundColor="#4ba862"
        BorderColor="#2b3c3c"
        BorderRadius="35"
        BorderWidth="1"
        FontAttributes="Bold"
        HeightRequest="70"
        HorizontalOptions="End"
        Text="Hello"
        TextColor="White"
        VerticalOptions="End"
        WidthRequest="160" />
</Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

**Code behind:**

```
public partial class Page2 : ContentPage
{
    public ObservableCollection<ColorsDataModel> colorsDataModels { get; set; }
    public Page2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        colorsDataModels = new ObservableCollection<ColorsDataModel> {
            new ColorsDataModel {
                Name = "Red",
                Color = Color.Red
            },
            new ColorsDataModel {
                Name = "Green",
                Color = Color.Green
            },
            new ColorsDataModel {
                Name = "Blue",
                Color = Color.Blue
            }
        };
        this.BindingContext = this;
    }
}
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can put  floating buttons by using grid.

You need to put CarouselView and Buttons on the same Grid Row.

This is a sample:

```
        <Grid >
            <CarouselView Grid.Row="0">
                <CarouselView.ItemsSource>
                    <x:Array Type="{x:Type ContentView}">
                        <ContentView>
                            <StackLayout BackgroundColor="Blue" />
                        </ContentView>
                        <ContentView>
                            <StackLayout BackgroundColor="Red">
                                <Label Text="Label inside of a simple ContentView" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                                <Button Text="dummy button" />
                            </StackLayout>
                        </ContentView>
                    </x:Array>
                </CarouselView.ItemsSource>
                <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ContentView Content="{Binding .}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
            </CarouselView>
            <StackLayout Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                <Button Text="tool1 button" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
                <Button Text="tool2 button" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
                <Button Text="tool3 button" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
            </StackLayout>
        </Grid>
```

Comment: I use ContentPage in this sample.

Answer (score 0):

By @deirahi

I tried use code as you sugguest but I got this error, and I use type of page as CarouselPage as display in image below,

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oDe6k.png)

Comment: Sorry,  I mistaked CarouselPage for CarouselView.
But by MSDocs, "The CarouselPage has been superseded by the CarouselView".
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/carousel-page 
So, you may need to replace CarouselPage with CarouselView, and use ContentPage instead of CarouselPage.

Comment: @ppungpong This could be a comment and not other post. Delete it and repost like comments...